# Fetch model values for edit Form Reactive Forms in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 8 app and I am trying to fetch a model and then fill out the values from the response into my reactive form.

my component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setForm();
  }
  loadData(){
    this.debtorService.getImport(parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))).subscribe( response =>{
      this.model= response,
      console.log(this.model),
      this.newEntryForm.patchValue(this.model);
    });
  }
  setForm() {
    this.newEntryForm = this.fb.group({
      PimFirstname: ['', Validators.required],
      PimLastname: ['', Validators.required],
      PimAccountNumber: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(25),
      ]],
    //other fields here.
    loadData();
```

My Html looks like so :

```
 <form [formGroup]="newEntryForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--Left side-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-1">First Name</label>
                            <input formControlName = "PimFirstname" name = "PimFirstname" type="text"  class="form-control" />
                            <div *ngIf="PimFirstname?.invalid && PimFirstname?.dirty"
                                class="text-danger"><small><strong>First Name Required</strong></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-1">Account Number</label>
                            <input formControlName = "PimAccountNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ACC#"
                                name="PimAccountNumber" />
                            <div *ngIf="PimAccountNumber?.invalid && (PimAccountNumber?.dirty || PimAccountNumber.touched)"
                                class="text-danger"><small><strong>Account Number Required</strong></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Right side-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-1">Last Name</label>
                            <input formControlName = "PimLastname" type="text" class="form-control"
                                name="PimLastname" />
                            <div *ngIf="PimLastname?.invalid && (PimLastname?.dirty || PimLastname?.touched)"
                                class="text-danger"><small><strong>Last Name Required</strong></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label mb-1">ID Number</label>
                            <input formControlName = "PimIdNumber" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Number*"
                                />
      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My model:

```
export interface Model {
  PimIdNumber: string;
  PimFirstname: string;
  PimLastname: string;
  PimAccountNumber: string;
}
```

From Console.log(this.model) I can see it returns the correct data but It doesn't seem to be filling out the form. Any ideas on what I could be missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What's the data structure of `this.model`? Can you post it?

Comment: I have added my model to the original question

Comment: putting this in your template show anything at all populated? <pre>{{  newEntryForm.value | json }}</pre>

Comment: @Thibs from the console.log(this.model) I can see that the model is populated.

Comment: But `this.model` isn't your form model, `this.newEntryForm.value` is.

Comment: `<pre>{{ newEntryForm.value | json }}</pre>` should show you what's in your form model while running the app.

Comment: @ToddSkelton thanks, I can see that the form does not seem to be populated at all. So console.log(this.model) is populated but they are not being patched to the form

Comment: What does the `console.log(this.model)` show? I don't see anything wrong with the `patchValue` call.

Comment: Many thanks @Todd I just realized that the json formatting from the API was switching to lower casing and this conflicted with the binding to the form.

Comment: I've ran into that problem many times. I know your pain.